# Detailed information in Lucene/Solr results

Tags: lucene, solr

After having performed a search in Lucene/Solr without having specified a field, how can I know in which fields of a result document the search string was found (and how often)?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [Query Highlighting](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters).

Comment: Query Highlighting will highlights all occurrences of a query in a field.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting `debugQuery=on`. See [this example](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#Why_does_id:archangel_come_before_id:hawkgirl_when_querying_for_.22wings.22).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, use debugQuery=true. The response will then include an "explain" section. By default, this will give you some awful formatted text that looks like this:

```
0.69102794 = (MATCH) weight(body:arrai^1.5 in 6357), product of:
  0.46610788 = queryWeight(body:arrai^1.5), product of:
    1.5 = boost
    5.591044 = idf(docFreq=55709, maxDocs=5492855)
    0.055577915 = queryNorm
  1.4825494 = (MATCH) fieldWeight(body:arrai in 6357), product of:
    2.828427 = tf(termFreq(body:arrai)=8)
    5.591044 = idf(docFreq=55709, maxDocs=5492855)
    0.09375 = fieldNorm(field=body, doc=6357)
```

For each match in each field, you will get a block like this that explains how SOLR computed the relevancy of this document to your query. What you're asking about (how many matches in this document's field) SOLR calls term frequency "tf". You can see this on the 7th line of the output i pasted above. In this line, SOLR is telling you that it found 8 matches for arrai in the field called "body".

The other lines stand for things like inverse document frequency-"idf" (how rare the matched term is) and fieldNorm, which relates to how short the document's field is relative to the match. You can learn about these here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ

FYI if you need this "explain" information in a structured format instead of clumsy text you can pass this parameter with your query: debug.explain.structured=true However, its still pretty hard to use = )